# How to print brandname with related to its categoryname in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model
1   juy   car           toyota       121
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d
4   hyu   van           ford         max
5   nhj   car           toyota       121
```

now I need print separately each brandnames with related to categoryname like this,

```
car
toyota
bmw

van
nissan
ford
```

how can I do this in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
    $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                    ->get();


    $cat = "";
    foreach($vehicles AS $vehicle) {
        if($vehicle->categoryname != $cat) {
            $cat = $vehicle->categoryname;
            echo $cat . '<br><br>';
        }

        echo $vehicle->brandname . '<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')->get();

$arr = [];

foreach($vehicles as $veh)
{
    if(isset( $arr[$veh->categoryname] ))
    {
       $arr[$veh->categoryname][] = $veh->brandname;
    } else 
    {
       $arr[$veh->categoryname][] = $veh->categoryname;
    }     

}

dd($arr);
```

Comment: is this controller function?

Comment: yup. `dd();` will should show the result you require. Please let me know if you have  any more questions.